# Somehow my Login Program isn't taking or saving or comparing my login strings correctly

Tags: c, string, if-statement

I want to write a login program.
However when I type in a user, The Program skips all my IFs. I think it might be a problem with the comparing of the strings. I am pretty new to using strings in more complex programs and don't quite know what to regard.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    char user[17] = "";
    char password[17] = "";
    char user1[17] = "strfad23";
    char user2[17] = "zmufad23";
    char user3[17] = "admin";
    char user4[17] = "WURZINGER";
    char pw1[20] = "WhyDoYouWantToKnow?";
    char pw2[17] = "HowShouldIKnow?";
    char pw3[17] = "2long2remember";
    char pw4[17] = "shortAndInsecure";
    int wrongLogins = 0;
    char repeat = 'A';

    login:

    printf("Enter your username: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", user);


    if(user == user1)
    {
        printf("Please enter your password, %s\n", user1);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s", password);
        if(password == pw1) printf("Hello Fabian!\n");
        else wrongLogins++;
    }
    else if(user == user2)
    {
        printf("Please enter your password, %s\n", user2);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s", password);
        if(password == pw2) printf("Hello Fabio CMugg!\n");
        else wrongLogins++;
    }
    else if(user == user4)
    {
        printf("Please enter your password, %s\n", user2);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s", password);
        if(password == pw4) printf("Hello Fabian Wutte!\n");
        else wrongLogins++;
    }else if(user == user3)
    {
        printf("Please enter your password, %s\n", user3);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s", password);
        if(password == pw3)
        {
        printf("Hello Administrator!\n");
        printf("There have been %d failed attempts of login on other accounts\n", wrongLogins);
        }
        else wrongLogins++;
    }
    else printf("user not found\n");


    printf("Do you want to login again?\n");
    printf("Y / N : ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c", &repeat);

    if(repeat == 'Y')goto login;

    return 0;
}
```

But as Output I only get this:

```
Enter your username: admin
user not found
Do you want to login again?
Y / N :
```

I want to get sth like that:

```
Enter your username: WURZINGER
Please enter your password, WURZINGER : shortAndInsecure
Hello Fabian!
Do you want to login again?
Y / N :
```

I added the error of "User not found" and made my program repeatable bc of the function I added when you login as admin.

Comment: Be cautious about [Using `fflush(stdin)`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209/15168)

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)